# How to get the URL from a localhost server without using libcurl

Tags: html, c, server, output

I've made a custom HTTP server that serves an HTML page with some text, an input text box for entering a command, and a submit button.  Upon receiving a form submission, the server is supposed to run the given command and serve a response containing the results.

The issue I cant quite figure out is how to get the URLs of form submission requests so as to parse out the command to run.  As presently implemented, the server runs on localhost:3838, and when the client browses to that URL the server responds correctly with the form.  When the user enters (say) the command `ls` in the text box and clicks the "run" submission button, a request is issued to `localhost:3838/run?command=ls`. How can I obtain that URL in the server, so as to parse out and execute the command?

Here's the present server code:

**CwebServer.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define PORT "3838" //port being connected to 
#define MAXLEN 800
#define BACKLOG 10 //number of pending connections to be held in queue

//format of html page 

char header []= 
"HTTP/1.1 200 Ok\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n"
"<html>\n"
"<head>\n"
"<title>Web-Based Remote Command Server</title>\r\n"
"</head>\n"
"<body>\n\n";
char input []=
"<form action= \"/run\" method= \"GET\"> \n"
"Command: <input type=\"text\" size=\"100\" name=\"command\">\n"
"<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Run\">\n"
"</form>";
char output []=
"<p>Command that was run and testing this:</p>\n"
"<pre>Your server will include the command that was just run here.</pre>\n\n"
"<p>Standard Output:</p>\n""<pre>Your server will include the stdout results here.</pre>\n\n"
"<p>Standard Error:</p>\n"
"<pre>Your server will include the stderr results here.</pre>\r\n\r\n"
"</body>\r\n""</html>\r\n";

char *buff = header; 

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    (void)s; // quiet unused variable warning

    // waitpid() might overwrite errno, so we save and restore it:
    int saved_errno = errno;

    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);

    errno = saved_errno;
}


void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}


int main (void){
    int sockfd;
    int new_fd; 
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *serverinfo; 
    struct addrinfo *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    socklen_t addrsize;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes = 1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int status;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); //makes struct empty 
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; //IPv4 or v6 
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; //TCP type need 
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; //Fill in IP for us 


    //if can't get address info print error 
    if((status = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &serverinfo)) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 1;
    }


    for(p = serverinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next){
        if((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1){
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1){
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1){
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(serverinfo);

    if(p == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1){
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections....\n");

    while(1){
        addrsize = sizeof client_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addrsize);
        if(new_fd == -1){
            perror("Did not accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(client_addr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&client_addr), s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if(!fork()){
            close(sockfd);
            int bufsize = 1024;
            char *buffer = malloc(bufsize);
            send(new_fd, header, bufsize, 0);
            //write(new_fd, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", 16);
            //write(new_fd, "Content-length: 46\n", 19);
            //write(new_fd, "Content-type: text/html\n\n", 25);
            //write(new_fd, "<html><head>\n<head>\n<title>The CAvengers Web Page</title>\n</head>\n</html>", 46);

            if(send(new_fd, buffer, MAXLEN, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);
    }

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: libcurl provides an API for making HTTP requests and receiving the corresponding responses.  You can implement what you need of that directly, instead, but if you're asking for details then that's far too broad a question.

Comment: I'm asking to do this without libcurl. All im asking really is how to pull that URL out and place it into a variable to be able to tokenize it for use.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having a lot of difficulty following what you're asking.  libcurl provides an HTTP *client*.  I understand that you don't want to use it, but inasmuch as you've asked for an alternative to libcurl, the answer is some variation on "implement your own HTTP client".  On the other hand, you have presented code for an HTTP *server*.  It's unclear how that factors in at all.  Overall, what are you trying to parse, and where?  An HTTP request, on the server (for which libcurl isn't relevant anyway)?  An HTTP response, on the client?  Something else?

Comment: I apologize for the confusing question i suppose i just made sense in my head but perhaps thats a piece of my problem. What i am trying to do with my HTTP server which runs strictly on localhost:3838 and when run has a text box, when you type in this text box a command like ls it then brings you to a URL of `localhost:3838/run?command=ls` what i am asking is how can i pull that URL out and place it into a variable. The rest i can figure out and do myself But in essence i am then going to pull the `ls` portion out and plug it into execvp and then plug that output back into the server to display

Comment: The lack of clarity seems to arise at least in part because you are not clearly distinguishing between the role of the server and the role of its clients.  I will see what I can do to clear that up.

Comment: thank you! i appreciate the help!

Comment: Ok, have a look at that and make sure I have captured your question accurately.

Comment: I already pointed out in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022754/server-displaying-text-instead-of-html?noredirect=1#comment98690433_56022754) that sending a fixed size that is longer than your content does not make much sense. Now you still send a size unrelated to the length and on top you also send some uninitialized memory content. Also as John Bollinger already mentioned, please clearly distinguish server from client.

Comment: Yes it correctly captures my question. and the uninitalized memory content was a placeholder i was hoping i could change to send in the commands information once i had done the parsing before hand.

Comment: The issue of memory can be fixed and doesnt exactly pertain to my question or issue though does it ?

Comment: Turns out the answer was as simple as making a recv, placing that into a variable and now i need to figure out the tokenizing and parsing it out but that shouldnt be too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web servers and clients communicate via the HTTP protocol.  That's what makes them *web* servers as opposed to some other kind.  HTTP is a request / response protocol: the client sends a request to the server *that contains information about what it's requesting*, and the server processes that request to determine how to respond.

Your particular server seems to intend to implement [HTTP 1.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html). This is not the most recent version of the protocol, but that's ok.  Pretty much every HTTP client in the world understands that dialect.  But yours is a pretty minimally-functioning server, responding to every established connection with the same HTTP response, even if the client does not actually send an HTTP request.

Your question is how to get the request URI.  The answer is to *read* it from the client, via the connected socket returned by `accept()`.  The `read()` or `recv()` function would be appropos for that.  The format you should expect the client to use is described in the HTTP specifications I linked above, but in *very* brief, you should expect the request to start with the request method name (`GET`), at least one space, the request URI, and a carriage-return / linefeed pair.  You will need to parse the request URI to distinguish between an initial request for the form and a form submission, and in the latter case you will be able to parse the query parameters as well.

DO NOTE, however, that although HTTP is a comparatively simple protocol, it is still much more complicated than I've just described.

Comment: thank you! Very informative. Im currently on the step where i have `run?command=ls` separated so now its just separating the last portion and then parsing the command and then its just sending the command to display, thank you!